# Graph not rendering my Date data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

Using javascript, D3.js and this is my first time dealing with D3. I began by using a working example but now it's not working:
[My Graph](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGMdNj?editors=0010)
This is the javascript code:

```
//************************************************************
// Data notice the structure
//************************************************************
var data =  [
    [
     {'x':'01/01/2016','y':0},{'x':'01/02/2016','y':5},
     {'x':'01/03/2016','y':1},{'x':'01/04/2016','y':0},
     {'x':'01/05/2016','y':6},{'x':'01/06/2016','y':1},
     {'x':'01/07/2016','y':5}
    ],
    [
     {'x':'01/01/2016','y':1},{'x':'01/02/2016','y':6},
     {'x':'01/03/2016','y':2},{'x':'01/04/2016','y':1},
     {'x':'01/05/2016','y':7},{'x':'01/06/2016','y':2},
     {'x':'01/07/2016','y':6}
    ]
    [
     {'x':'01/01/2016','y':2},{'x':'01/02/2016','y':7},
     {'x':'01/03/2016','y':3},{'x':'01/04/2016','y':2},
     {'x':'01/05/2016','y':5},{'x':'01/06/2016','y':3},
     {'x':'01/07/2016','y':7}
    ]
];

var colors = [
    'steelblue',
    'green',
    'red'
]

var minDate = data[0][0].x;
var len = data[0].length;
var maxDate = data[0][len - 1].x;
console.log("minDate: "+minDate);
console.log("maxDate: "+maxDate);
//************************************************************
// Create Margins and Axis and hook our zoom function
//************************************************************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(minDate), new Date(maxDate)])
    // .domain([ 0, 12 ])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 16])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
  .ticks(5) // fixes the duplicate date issue until zooming in enough
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickPadding(10)    
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%x"))

    .orient("bottom");  

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("left");

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);    

//************************************************************
// Generate our SVG object
//************************************************************  
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .call(zoom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 10)
    .attr("x", -height/2)
    .text('Bullshit');  

svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


// svg.xAxis
//   .tickFormat(function(d) {
//     return d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y")(new Date(d));
// })

// svg.xScale(d3.time.scale());
//************************************************************
// Create D3 line object and draw data on our SVG object
//************************************************************
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")  
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });     

svg.selectAll('.line')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr('stroke', function(d,i){          
        return colors[i%colors.length];
    })
    .attr("d", line);       




//************************************************************
// Draw points on SVG object based on the data given
//************************************************************
var points = svg.selectAll('.dots')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "dots")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");   

points.selectAll('.dot')
    .data(function(d, index){       
        var a = [];
        d.forEach(function(point,i){
            a.push({'index': index, 'point': point});
        });     
        return a;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class','dot')
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr('fill', function(d,i){    
        return colors[d.index%colors.length];
    })  
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
    );






//************************************************************
// Zoom specific updates
//************************************************************
function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    // svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);   
    svg.selectAll('path.line').attr('d', line);  

    points.selectAll('circle').attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
    );  
}
```

So I am trying to render the sample data at the top of the post. My end goal is to have a graph with three plotted lines that have points at each x,y coordinate, much like this graph: [Original Graph](http://codepen.io/pdillon/pen/bEgmA?editors=0010).

Again, I am not very experienced with D3 and I have tried looking for examples (and I found some) but I still could not get my graph to display my lines. Right now if you check the console on my graph I have the following errors:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,
>   423.52941176470586LNaN,
>   291.17647058823525LNaN,
>   397.05882352941177LNaN,
>   423.52941176470586LNaN,
>   264.70588235294116LNaN,
>   397.05882352941177LNaN,
>   291.17647058823525"
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

My own conclusions, which are probably vague, tell me that I'm not parsing the data correctly.

I should add that, the graph displays duplicate dates if you zoom in, I am not sure if that might be the problem; maybe the graph is getting confused on which data point to plot on? (Which by the way, the duplicate dates, is another problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a date formatter to convert your string in x `('01/01/2016')` into Date:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");
```

and using this formatter to convert your date into date object.

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([format.parse(minDate), format.parse(maxDate)])
```

and same formatter in line function too

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("linear")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(format.parse(d.x));//convert into date
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  });
```

Working example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyywEY?editors=0010)

Comment: Hmm. I feel ridiculous. I was almost certain I tried this! Thank you! One thing though, I noticed that the console is printing out errors for <circle>. Do you know why aren't the datapoints being processed to render the points on the graph?

Comment: Nothing new same mistake :) should have been `x(format.parse(d.point.x))` to convert it into date corrected fiddle here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxxwMe?editors=0010

Comment: Wow. I suppose I have a long way to go to learn D3 then. Thanks again for the help; as ridiculous as this problem was I have actually spent at least day or so trying to figure out why it wasn't working!

Answer (score 1):

[d3.time.scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#_scale) function takes in a javascript date object.

in your line function, you feed a date string. You need to parse the date string into a javascript date object first before you pass it into the function.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("linear")
  .x(function(d) {

    return x(new Date(d.x));
    console.log(d.x, x(new Date(d.x))); // x(new Date(d.x)) now doesn't return NAN =]
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  });
```

Comment: Ooops! I saw the other guys' response first, I don't know how I scrolled through this one. I tried your example and it also works! Thank you! However, I do have the same question for you as I did for @Cyril, Do you know why the points on the graph are no longer being plotted??